# How do I import .iex.exs automatically before hitting a pry breakpoint in iex?

Tags: debugging, elixir, elixir-iex

When starting iex normally (`iex -S mix` or `iex`), it will run the `.iex.exs` file in the current directory (or `~/.iex.exs`).  If running tests, if there is a pry (`require IEx; IEx.pry`) it will pause execution and open a prompt.  However this means that `~/.iex.exs` will not be read until after finishing the test suite.

I would like to have the aliases/functions I define in `.iex.exs` available, so I'd like to run that file.  I know that I can run:

```
import_file_if_available(".iex.exs")
```

But ideally I'd like it to happen automatically.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I believe this answers your question :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/71488299/15693750

Comment: Yes, I think that would do it, thank you!