# iex.iexs file is not loading on test environment

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I'am trying to load the `iex.iexs` file when debugging a test. I created an `alias` in `Mix.exs` that tries to import it.

```
defp aliases do
    [
      ...,
      "ex.file": [&import_iex_file/1, "compile"]
    ]
  end

  defp import_iex_file(_var) do
    require IEx.Helpers
    # This raises a File.Error if ~/.iex.exs doesn't exist.
    if "./.iex.exs" |> Path.expand() |> File.exists?() do
      IEx.Helpers.import_file("./.iex.exs")
    end
  end
```

When I run a test with `iex -S mix test_path` the file is loaded, but when it stop at the `IEx.pry` I can't access the aliases that I added at the `.iex.iex` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the file name should be `.iex.exs`.  As you have noticed, running tests does not start an `IEx` session, so the file is not loaded.  Instead, it might be better to do whatever setups you need for tests inside your `tests/test_helper.exs` file.  If you really need to re-use the settings/shortcuts in your `.iex.exs` file, you can include it from your `test_helper.exs` file something like this:

```
# tests/test_helper.exs
require IEx.Helpers
IEx.Helpers.import_file(".iex.exs")
ExUnit.start()
```